# Java clock accuracy on Windows: 15-16ms

Tags: java, windows, java-time

The clock accuracy on Windows seems to have changed lately. I remember it being very accurate since Windows 7 (1 ms resolution), and now the time hops in steps of 15 to 16 ms. I noticed due to some (albeit poorly written) unit tests failing (tests checked that some time elapsed between writing and reading records).

This affects following implementations:

- `System.currentTimeMillis()`
- `LocalTime.now()`
- `LocalDateTime.now()`
- `ZonedDateTime.now()`

I'm well aware that elapsed time is to be measured using `System.nanoTime()` deltas, but I'm wondering nevertheless if I missed something that changed back the clock resolution to 15-16ms.

Environment:

- Windows 10 version 1709
- JRE/JDK **1.8.0_171-b11** (64-bit)

Did anyone notice this as well? What could be the reason for this resolution change?

**EDIT:** 
Test code to check this behaviour (see output: time changes and number of samples before change)

```
@Test
public void testCurrentTimeMillis() {
    test(() -> System.currentTimeMillis());
}

@Test
public void testNanoTime() {
    test(() -> System.nanoTime());
}

@Test
public void testLocalTime() {
    test(() -> LocalTime.now());
}

@Test
public void testLocalDateTime() {
    test(() -> LocalDateTime.now());
}

@Test
public void testZonedDateTime() {
    test(() -> ZonedDateTime.now());
}

private <T> void test(Supplier<T> timeSupplier) {

    int samples = 20;
    String lastTimeString = null;
    int count = 0;
    while (samples > 0) {

        count++;
        String timeString = timeSupplier.get().toString();
        if (!timeString.equals(lastTimeString)) {
            System.out.println(timeString + " (" + count + ")");
            lastTimeString = timeString;
            count = 0;
            samples--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have windows developer mode on?

Comment: @ShanuGupta: no, it's off (on 'Sideload Apps')

Comment: Can you turn on and check again? You might have to restart system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timer accuracy in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245388/timer-accuracy-in-java)

Comment: @OleV.V. the other question dates back to 2009, back then such inacurracies were common on 32-bit Windows platforms. My case is a recent 64-bit Windows platform, where the problem resurfaced.

Comment: @ShanuGupta developer mode activated & restarted - same effect.

Comment: I’ve searched a bit around in vain. You can probably do better. Anyway IIRC, I read recently that this is a Windows issue (in 2018 still) and therefore not something that can be solved in Java alone. There are some tricks to persuade Windows to giving a better resolution, but they are expensive in power consumption, so you should use them with care if at all. There is also a JDK bug open that aims at better accuracy on Windows. Disclaimer: as I said, it’s all from fragile memory.

Comment: Just ran the test code on a collegue's machine - he's getting 1ms resolutions (same machine build, windows version, only the latest windows security updates KBID 4093110,4099989,4093112 from 2018-04-11 not installed). Maybe the resolution has been lowered as a countermeasure to SPECTRE vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2):

To get the **local time with the best accuracy regardless of the platform**, I came up with a solution with is based on the current time (measuring when it is increased) as an anchor, and and offset based on `System.nanoTime()` deltas.

Advantages:

- current time with precision not depending on the platform
- high accuracy (nano time)
- portable (as the `java.time` objects can actually carry nanosecond precision).

Code (can be adapted to serve `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime` as well):

```
/**
 * Exact zoned date/time, compensates for the 15-16ms leaps 
 * of milliseconds time on some Java platforms.
 */
public final class ExactZonedDateTime {

    private static ZonedDateTime anchor;
    private static long anchorNanos;

    static {
        ZonedDateTime last = ZonedDateTime.now();
        while (((anchor = ZonedDateTime.now()).equals(last))) {
            anchorNanos = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }

    private ExactZonedDateTime() {
    }

    public static ZonedDateTime now() {
        return anchor.plusNanos(System.nanoTime() - anchorNanos);
    }
}
```

Subsequent calls:

> 2018-04-26T12:51:02.293079632+02:00[Europe/Zurich]
>   2018-04-26T12:51:02.293524865+02:00[Europe/Zurich]
>   2018-04-26T12:51:02.293598126+02:00[Europe/Zurich]
>   2018-04-26T12:51:02.293660770+02:00[Europe/Zurich]
>   2018-04-26T12:51:02.293725538+02:00[Europe/Zurich]